# flag.PrintDefaults includes `-test` flags

Tags: go, command-line

I am building a CLI application in Go.

```
flag.IntVar(&connections, "c", 1, "Connections to keep open per endpoint")
flag.IntVar(&duration, "T", 10, "Exit after the specified amount of time in seconds")
flag.IntVar(&txsRate, "r", 1000, "Txs per second to send in a connection")
flag.BoolVar(&verbose, "v", false, "Verbose output")

flag.Usage = func() {
    fmt.Println(`....`)
    fmt.Println("Flags:")
    flag.PrintDefaults()
}

flag.Parse()

if flag.NArg() == 0 {
    flag.Usage()
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

([Full listing on Github](https://github.com/tendermint/tools/blob/develop/tm-bench/main.go))

For some strange reason, the above snippet produces:

```
Flags:


-T int
        Exit after the specified amount of time in seconds (default 10)
  -c int
        Connections to keep open per endpoint (default 1)
  -r int
        Txs per second to send in a connection (default 1000)
  -test.bench regexp
        run only benchmarks matching regexp
  -test.benchmem
        print memory allocations for benchmarks
  -test.benchtime d
        run each benchmark for duration d (default 1s)
  -test.blockprofile file
        write a goroutine blocking profile to file
  -test.blockprofilerate rate
        set blocking profile rate (see runtime.SetBlockProfileRate) (default 1)
  -test.count n
        run tests and benchmarks n times (default 1)
  -test.coverprofile file
        write a coverage profile to file
  -test.cpu list
        comma-separated list of cpu counts to run each test with
  -test.cpuprofile file
        write a cpu profile to file
  -test.memprofile file
        write a memory profile to file
  -test.memprofilerate rate
        set memory profiling rate (see runtime.MemProfileRate)
  -test.mutexprofile string
        write a mutex contention profile to the named file after execution
  -test.mutexprofilefraction int
        if >= 0, calls runtime.SetMutexProfileFraction() (default 1)
  -test.outputdir dir
        write profiles to dir
  -test.parallel n
        run at most n tests in parallel (default 2)
  -test.run regexp
        run only tests and examples matching regexp
  -test.short
        run smaller test suite to save time
  -test.timeout d
        fail test binary execution after duration d (0 means unlimited)
  -test.trace file
        write an execution trace to file
  -test.v
        verbose: print additional output
  -v    Verbose output
```

Any ideas why Go includes `-test` flags? Thanks!

Comment: You're importing the "testing" package.

Comment: https://github.com/tendermint/tools/blob/develop/tm-bench/main.go don't think so... but it certainly looks like the testing package is messing things up

Comment: What is the exact command line you build your binary with?

Comment: I am using `go build`

Comment: The program indirectly imports `github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/log`
 which imports the `testing` package.  Find a way to break the dependency on the the `testing` package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using go build but I also see the -test flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243919/using-go-build-but-i-also-see-the-test-flags/42244265#42244265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have a bunch f dependencies in your code. I have found that library `github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/log` has a dependency to a package `testing` from standard library: [searches for testing](https://github.com/tendermint/tmlibs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=testing&type=). And this standard library has all flags you are wondered about: [testing package](https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go)